# Access denied for user 'myUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, privileges, mysql-connect

Does that `(using password: YES)` means password is not matching ?

I am getting this error even I , as root user, has granted privileges to all the databases to the user !

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'prashant'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_secure_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Also, phpmyadmin shows `GRANT = NO` in the privileges table for the specified user.

I would like to add that there are several databases, some of them, I am able to connect , but some of them fails. Also, I have not added any table specific privilege to the user !

**UPDATE**

I tried to access those databases with root user n password , still getting the same error :(

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I don't know what was the issue ! I restarted mysql and everything is OK now ! Would love to hear any explanations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly giving the wrong password.